# Login to a site via C#

Tags: c#, authentication, automation

I have a problem about log-in to a site, here is my code (Visual studio 2010,form application) (Also I am kinda newbie)

What should I add to my form ? I tried to make it but I could not do it.

```
HttpWebRequest request;
HttpWebResponse response;
CookieContainer cookies;

string url = string.Format("http://extabit.com/login.jsp.login={0}&passwd={1}", cboUserName.Text, txtPassWord.Text);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Found)
{
//ToDo: if the page wasn't found raise Exception
//instead of this textmessage
MessageBox.Show("Something Wrong");
response.Close();
request.KeepAlive = false;
return;
}
cookies = request.CookieContainer;
response.Close();
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http://extabit.com);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
{
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
string line;
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
//todo read the page contents
}
```

Comment: "I tried to make it but I could not do it" is not a good description of the problem. What is not working? What do you expect that isn't happening? Errors? Exceptions?

Comment: When I add it to new form, I am getting 18 error.How can I prevent them, it is my question.Or am I doing it wrong ? (I mentioned that I am newbie) http://lulzimg.com/view/6993bcd989.jpg

Comment: What errors? What kind of errors?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add your namespaces.

You need to include `System.IO` and `System.Net`.

At the top of your file add the two using statements

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
```

Comment: Now I have 3 errors.I can handle it the other parts, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer but more advice - I strongly reccomend that you avoid passing in the username and password via the query string. The fact you're using '.Text' from a server control strongly suggests their not even encrypted.